# TikZ - pgfdeclaredecoration vs. curved path

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgf-decorations

I want to use a complex decoration, and then apply it to a curved path. It seems as if TikZ does not bend single segments though. Do you have any idea how I could get the desired behavior?

Is there maybe a way to add paths, similar to the stacked plots in pgfplots?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}

\pgfdeclaredecoration{reserve}{initial}
{
  \state{initial}[width=\pgfdecoratedpathlength]
  {
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{-4pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0.15*\pgfdecoratedpathlength}{7pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0.2*\pgfdecoratedpathlength}{-7pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0.35*\pgfdecoratedpathlength}{5pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0.4*\pgfdecoratedpathlength}{-5pt}}
    \pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{0.5*\pgfdecoratedpathlength}{3pt}}{\pgfpoint{0.6*\pgfdecoratedpathlength}{-3pt}}{\pgfpoint{0.6*\pgfdecoratedpathlength}{-3pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0.65*\pgfdecoratedpathlength}{6pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0.82*\pgfdecoratedpathlength}{-7pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0.9*\pgfdecoratedpathlength}{7pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0.97*\pgfdecoratedpathlength}{-2pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgfdecoratedpathlength}{0pt}}
  }
  \state{final}
  {
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast}
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[black, decorate, decoration={name=reserve}, very thick] (0,5) -- (5, 5) ;
  \draw[black, decorate, decoration={name=reserve}, very thick] (0,0) to[bend left] (5, 0) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: decoration applied to straight and curved line]

Comment: You would get a better result with a meta decoration

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Decorations work by breaking things into small sections and fitting them to the path independently.  I couldn't get it to work using \pgfdecoratedpathlength, though.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}

\pgfdeclaredecoration{reserve}{initial}
{
  \state{initial}[width=1cm,next state=break1]
  {
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{-4pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0.75cm}{7pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{1cm}{-7pt}}
  }
  \state{break1}[width=1cm,next state=break2]
  {
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{.75cm}{5pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{1cm}{-5pt}}
  }
  \state{break2}[width=1cm,next state=break3]
  {
    \pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{.5cm}{3pt}}{\pgfpoint{1cm}{-3pt}}{\pgfpoint{1cm}{-3pt}}%
  }
  \state{break3}[width=1cm,next state=break4]
  {
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{.25cm}{6pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{1cm}{-7pt}}
  }
  \state{break4}[width=1cm]
  {
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{.5cm}{7pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{.9cm}{-2pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{1cm}{0pt}}
  }
  \state{final}
  {
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast}
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[black, decorate, decoration={name=reserve}, very thick] (0,5) -- (5cm,5) ;
  \draw[black, decorate, decoration={name=reserve}, very thick] (0,0) to[bend left] (5, 0) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: decoration]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! This works in my case, as I only need to use the decoration for one specific picture and thus am not dependent on the \pgfdecoratedpathlength